# What was Protein G named after?

Tags: molecular-biology, nomenclature, protein-binding, history, immunoglobin

[Protein G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_G) (the bacterial antibody binding protein) is often used to pulldown antibodies, for example in chromatin immunoprecipitation (ChIP) experiments.

However, I was unable to find a site describing the history of the said protein, and how the name of Protein G came about, due to the fact that the similarly named (but completely different) G protein came up higher in search results.

What was Protein G named after? For example, [Protein A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_A) was named after the antibody fraction in which it was found, and [G protein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G_protein) was named because it bound GDP and GTP.

Comment: [This paper](http://m.jimmunol.org/content/135/4/2589.short) seems to suggest that protein G is so named because it was isolated from group G streptococci.

Comment: @canadianer is correct. Group G comes from Lancefield serum type G and it was a method that used to be used to classify bacterium and Group G Streptococci could be identified using this method. The protein was isolated from G148 S.aureus. Canadianer should post as an answer. +1

Comment: G148 is a Streptococcus strain. I incorrectly used the Genus and Species for Staphylococcus aureus in my prior comment. Protein A was isolated in S.aureus, Protein G in Streptococcus G148.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @canadianer mentions in his comment, Protein G is more than likely named after the human group G strain of Streptococci, G148.

> Protein G, a bacterial cell wall protein with affinity for immunoglobulin G (IgG), has been isolated from a human group G streptococcal strain (G148).

[Purification and some properties of streptococcal protein G, a novel IgG-binding reagent.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=6234364) - Björck et.al.

Protein G is a  Streptococcus protein that can bind the the Fc portion of the Immunoglobulin G protein. While it is similar to protein A, it was found to have better binding affinities to the different varieties of heavy chain constant regions of IgG molecules.

The G comes from [Lancefield grouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lancefield_grouping). Lancefield grouping was a method that used to be used to classify bacterium. Group G Streptococci could be identified using Lancefield serum type G and that is how they received their classification.